# Problema com o scroll horizontal ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Tenho o CKEditor 4 no meu cms e que quando coloco um texto grande não da para fazer scroll, ja estive a procura de um solução e não encontro, contudo analisando o código deparo que no html do iframe existe um **style:"overflow-y:hidden"** alguém sabe como retirar isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, mostre mais seu código e tente não colocar como print.

Comment: Cara isso deve ser resolvido com alguma config da api provavelmente. Da uma olhada na documentação oficial que deve encontrar alguma coisa. Mas como o código está dentro do iFrame vc não vai conseguir mudar só com CSS ,a sua página

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que exista algum arquivo `css` atribuindo `overflow=hidden` para esse elemento.

Como não foi acrescentado muita informação, vou usar um atributo do próprio CKEditor para aplicar um estilo à esse elemento.

Dentro da pasta onde contém seus arquivo do plugin, existe um arquivo chamado `config.js`, dentro desse arquivo você irá encontrar a configuração para seu editor.

No arquivo haverá a seguinte linha: `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {`, antes do fechamento da função inclua essa linha `config.contentsCss = 'html {overflow-y: scroll}';`

---

Caso seja apenas nessa página esse problema, você pode chamar um script para resolver o problema apenas nessa página.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('ID_COMPONENTE', {
     contentsCss : 'html {overflow-y: scroll}'
}
```

Referência : [contentsCss](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss)